# print field before and after matching pattern of single line

Tags: linux, text-processing

My file contains the data below:

```
tail fn0 logfile
more  tail3 fn0 logfile1
get than tail4 fn0 logfile2
```

I want to get output from the field before fn0 and the field after fn0.

Expected output:

```
tail logfile
tail3 logfile1
tail4 logfile2
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -v pattern="fn0" '{for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i==pattern) print $(i-1),$(i+1) }}' file
```

or if you want to use a regex pattern:

```
awk -v pattern="^fn0$" '{for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i~pattern) print $(i-1),$(i+1) }}' file
```

Output:

```
tail logfile
tail3 logfile1
tail4 logfile2
```

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -lane '($i) = grep {$F[$_] eq "fn0"} 0..$#F;
              print "$F[$i-1] $F[$i+1]"' ip.txt
tail logfile
tail3 logfile1
tail4 logfile2
```

- `-l` will remove newline character from input line, and add it back while printing
- `-a` split input line based on whitespaces, `@F` array will have the data
- `($i) = grep {$F[$_] eq "fn0"} 0..$#F` get index of the element whose exact content is `fn0`
- `print "$F[$i-1] $F[$i+1]"` print the required fields

With `sed` that supports ERE

```
$ sed -E 's/^(.* )?([^ ]+) fn0 ([^ ]+).*/\2 \3/' ip.txt
tail logfile
tail3 logfile1
tail4 logfile2
```

- `^(.* )?` optional fields at start of line
- `([^ ]+) fn0 ([^ ]+)` capture fields before and after `fn0` (assuming single space as field separator)
- `.*` rest of the line
- `\2 \3` required fields in output

Answer (score 0):

a solution with grep and sed:

`egrep -oh '[a-zA-Z0-9]+\ fn0\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+' testfile | sed 's/ fn0 / /'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/.*\(tail[[:digit:]]*\) fn[[:digit:]]*/\1/' file
tail logfile
tail3 logfile1
tail4 logfile2
```

The `sed` expression is replaces everything on each line up to some substring matching `tailXX fnYY` with `tailXX` (where `XX` and `YY` are some positive integers).